# Using qsort() with multiple types

Tags: c

I'd like to use C's qsort() function to sort arrays each having different types, like these:

```
int a[] = {1, 2, 3};
const char *b[] = {"foo", "bar", "bas"};
my_defined_type_t *c[100]; for (i=0; i<100; i++) { fill(c[i]); }
```

Is it necessary to write comparison functions for each type, like intComparator(), stringComparitor(), myDefinedTypeComparitor() and make calls to qsort with each comparison function in turn, or can something like this be done in C:

```
int myGrandUnifiedComparisonFunction(const void* a, const void* b) {

if *a, *b are integers: intComparatorCode;
if *a, *b are strings: stringComparitorCode;
if *a, *b are my_defined_type_t's: myDefinedTypeComparitorCode;
/* etc. */

}
```

Comment: `*a, *b` wrong, error for `void*`, we have void pointers not void value

Comment: and how would your GUCF know whether a and b were ints, strings or anything else?

Comment: just.. dont.. Use typesafety as much as you can. It is there to help you

Comment: @Vicky Somehow I'd like C to do that: dynamic type checking of some kind?

Comment: @user1505713 no. Looks like you want to write `python` code

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems to consider:

**1) The Problem of Information**

Your comparison function gets handed two void pointers. That's just some bit patterns which could mean anything. C attaches no information to, for example, floats or character pointers, so it's impossible to tell if some piece of data is the one or the other if you don't know beforehand.

That said, you can attach this information yourself by wrapping you data in a struct together with an enum value telling you what's inside. But you wouldn't technically be comparing floats or char pointers, but wrapped floats and wrapped char pointers. Something like:

```
enum { Float, String, MyType } typ;

typedef struct { 
    typ t;
    union {
       float f;
       char *s;
       myType mt;
    } wrappedData;
```

Then you can just write one function which compares `wrappedData *`.
That's just about what every dynamic language does.

And then, even your grand unified function would still have to compare them appropriately, that is, differently for each type, so you wouldn't have gained much. On the contrary, you would mould logic together into one function which doesn't really belong together.

**2) The Problem of Efficiency**

While this may not bother you, unwrapping a pointer and checking it's type would be done with every single comparison operation, which may increase the runtime of your sort by a lot.

**Conclusion:**

You'd have to go some way and wrap your data, for a dubious advantage and a significant disadvantage (efficiency). Don't do it.

Answer (score 2):

C have no [introspection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introspection_%28computer_science%29), so there's no way of knowing what type a `void*` is pointing to.

You need one comparison function per type, and have to call `qsort` with the correct callback.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of

```
int myGrandUnifiedComparisonFunction(const void* a, const void* b) {

    if *a, *b are integers: intComparatorCode;
    if *a, *b are strings: stringComparitorCode;
    if *a, *b are my_defined_type_t's: myDefinedTypeComparitorCode;
   /* etc. */
}
```

Is pretty great. Have you tried implementing it?

The problem is that **there is no way of implementing it in C or C++**. There is no way of determining what kind of variable the `void*` points to.

Comment: yes in fact dereference void pointer without cast is compilation time error -- an example of **semantic error**

Answer (score 0):

No you can not have a generic function because types are now passed in C at runtime (unlike in Object-oriented languages). The type has to be known at compile time.

Thus you need to have a function that knows how to compare each type and tell `qsort` that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can if you somehow magically know the types, but why bother?  Also, you've got the size to pass in as well so you'd need to do the check in 2 places.

Not sure what the advantage of this is.